# Parcelable List that contains a custom object

Tags: java, android, parcelable

I am trying to pass data (`ArrayList`) between `Activities` on `Android`

All works fine when the class that implements `Parcelable`doesn´t contains custom objects (Shop), but  what do I have to do if my class contains one?

Shop

```
public Shop(Parcel in) {
    this.id  = in.readString();
    this.name = in.readString();
    this.type = in.readString();
    this.lat= in.readDouble();
    this.long= in.readDouble();
}
@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {

    dest.writeString(this.id);
    dest.writeString(this.name);
    dest.writeString(this.type);
    dest.writeDouble(this.lat);
    dest.writeDouble(this.long);
}

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator() {
    public Shop createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Shop(in);
    }

    public Shop[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Shop[size];
    }
};
```

And here is my other class Offer which is the one that contains an object of Shop

```
public Offer(Parcel in) {
    this.id  = in.readInt();
    this.title = in.readString();
    this.myShop = in.read.......();
}


@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {

    dest.writeInt(this.id);
    dest.writeString(this.title);
    dest.write......(this.myShop);
}
```

Which data type should I read and write ?

Thank you very much!

Comment: your custom object has to be parcelable or serializable as well

Comment: @blackbelt it is Parceable, but which method is able to read and write it?

Comment: read and write parcelable ?

Comment: Please see my answer below, and accept it if I helped solving this. Thank you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your `Shop` class should implement `Parcelable` and you should use

```
public Offer(Parcel in) {
    this.id  = in.readInt();
    this.title = in.readString();
    this.myShop = in.readParcelable(Shop.class.getClassLoader());
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeInt(this.id);
    dest.writeString(this.title);
    dest.writeParcelable(this.myShop, flags);
}
```

Comment: After doing this, i am getting: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to android.os.Parcelable

Comment: in my case, myShop is basically a custom array list

Comment: for arraylist use this `myShop = new ArrayList<Shop>();
    parcel.readList(myShop, Shop.class.getClassLoader());`